# Explicit tracks in Spotify always returns None?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, spotify

I am getting a list of my 50 top artists `artistList`. From this list I get the albums of each artist in `artistAlbumsList`, from which I then loop through the tracks of the artist's albums until I hit an explicit track in `albumTracks`.

*(Spotify does not flag albums as explicit, only the tracks...this is why I have to loop through the tracks.)*

**If there is an explicit track, I flag the album as explicit and add the album to my `new_albums` list.**

**How come I am returning `None`? *There are explicit tracks in all of these albums, so this is not the issue.***

Additionally, if I instead try to call the `update` on the `albums` dictionary instead of `new_albums`, I get this error: `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'update'`

```
import time
import spotipy
import spotipy.util as util
from config import spotify_token

def albumDrop():
    sp = spotipy.Spotify(auth=spotify_token)
    albums = {}
    new_albums = {}
    artistList = sp.current_user_top_artists(limit=50, offset=0, time_range='long_term')['items']
    for artist in artistList:
        print(artist["name"], artist["id"])
        artistAlbumsList = sp.artist_albums( artist["id"], album_type='album', limit=3)['items']
        for album in artistAlbumsList:
            print(album['release_date'], artist['name'], album['name'], album['external_urls']['spotify'], album['id'])
            albumTracks = sp.album_tracks(album['id'], limit=50)['items']
            for track in albumTracks:
                if track['explicit'] == True:
                    new_albums = albums.update({'{artistName} - {albumName}'.format(artistName = artist['name'], albumName = album['name']) : {'Release Date': album['release_date'], 'Artist Name': artist['name'], 'Album Name': album['name'], 'Album URI': album['external_urls']['spotify'], 'Album ID': album['id'], 'Explicit': track['explicit']}})
                    break
    return(new_albums)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    start = time.time()
    latestAlbums = albumDrop()
    end = time.time()
    print(latestAlbums)
    print(end - start)
```

**Is there any faster way to do this also?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`albums.update` or `dict.update` is an in-place operation which returns `None`.

You can use unpacking to create a new dict:

```
new_albums = {**albums, **{'{artistName} - {albumName}'.format(artistName = artist['name'], albumName = album['name']) : {'Release Date': album['release_date'], 'Artist Name': artist['name'], 'Album Name': album['name'], 'Album URI': album['external_urls']['spotify'], 'Album ID': album['id'], 'Explicit': track['explicit']}}}
```

Comment: Yes you can :) In such a case just `return(albums)` instead of `new_albums`

Comment: using just ```albums.update``` instead of ```new_albums = albums.update``` no longer returns ```None```. I do not wish to have to createra new dictionary, just update the current one.